# To sort the numbers using java

Tags: java

```
class sort {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[], i, j, n, temp;
        n = args.length;
        for (i = 0; i <n; i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I found some error in my program please check it out. some error in arr[] is coming but i am not able to find the actual problem

Comment: Why are you writing your own sort routine instead of using the one provided by the library?

Comment: Actually i am very new i java. so i am not aware of much library.

Comment: If there was a compiler error, you should always include that information in your post. If there was a runtime error, show us the last few jumps in the stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

In this code

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

but without providing the exception thrown, its not possible to say.

Can you post what the actual error is and where it occurs?

---

I suspect

```
for(j=1+1; j<=n; j++)
```

should be

```
for(j= i +1; j < n; j++)
```

but you should really be using `Arrays.sort(arr)` and `Arrays.toString(arr)`

Comment: I replaced the number `1`+1 with outer loop variable `i`+1 ;)

Answer (score 4):

You never initialized `arr`. An array is an object, and needs to be "newed" up before it can be used.

```
arr = new int[100]; //Sets size of array to hold 100 integers
```

or for your case

```
arr = new int[args.length];
```

It needs to know how much memory to allocate (how many integers to store).  Make sure you initialize the array using the code above *before* you attempt to access it in the following line:

```
arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(args [i]);
```

This code should have given you a compiler error

> Variable arr might not have been initialized

Comment: @Alok hope it helps. Be sure to use a size meaningful for your situation, rather than the 100 I used for demonstration :)

Comment: It is obvious from the code that OP needs a `new int[args.length]`.

Comment: Thanks Marko, I didn't really read the context, just immediately picked up the error. I'll add that in

Answer (score 2):

Its better to use `Collections.sort(List list);`

```
List<Integer> list=new ArrayList();
 for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
        }
Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the equal sign in the last loop and your program will run good!!